# C++ 11 alternative pthread_cond_timedwait

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, timeout, pthreads

I need to make a thread waiting until either

- a timeout is expired, or
- a variable is changed by another thread

After some research I've found out pthreads got  **pthread_cond_timedwait** which could be useful in this case if I'd be using pthreads.

I'm using C++ 11 threads instead. Is there a suitable alternative for me without completely passing to pthreads?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you want [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) from `<condition_variable>`, which has a member function `wait_for` that takes a time duration.

> The condition_variable class is a synchronization primitive that can
>   be used to block a thread, or multiple threads at the same time,
>   until:
>
> - a notification is received from another thread
> - a timeout expires